# Shared schema multi tenancy implementation with Hibernate and Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate

Can I build a multi tenant application (using shared schema approach) with Spring and Hibernate?

At the moment, we get the tenant id from the user's profile and then execute repository methods. I need to do this for every kind of request that is coming in. Can this be avoided? I cannot use spring's data rest in my current setup as this would return data for all tenants.

Comment: A good article about it you could get on [Spring blog](https://spring.io/blog/2022/07/31/how-to-integrate-hibernates-multitenant-feature-with-spring-data-jpa-in-a-spring-boot-application)